# Tensorflow VarLenFeature vs FixedLenFeature

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was trying to save images of different sizes into tf-records. I found that even though the images have different sizes, I can still load them with `FixedLenFeature`.

By checking the docs on `FixedLenFeature` and `VarLenFeature`,  I found the difference seems to be that `VarLenFeauture` returns a sparse tensor.

Could anyone illustrate some situations one should use `FixedLenFeature` or `VarLenFeature`?

Comment: What feature type u use for saving image data? tf.train.BytesList?

Comment: Yes, I'm using tf.train.Byteslist

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can load images probably beacause you saved them using feature type `tf.train.BytesList()` and whole image data is one big byte value inside a list.

If I'm right you're using `tf.decode_raw` to get the data out of the image you load from TFRecord.

Regarding example use cases:
I use `VarLenFeature` for saving datasets for object detection task:
There's variable amount of bounding boxes per image (equal to object in image) therefore I need another feature `objects_number` to track amount of objects (and bboxes).
Each bounding box itself is a list of 4 float coordinates

I'm using following code to load it:

```
features = tf.parse_single_example(
    serialized_example,
    features={
        # We know the length of both fields. If not the
        # tf.VarLenFeature could be used
        'height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'depth': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        # Label part
        'objects_number': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'bboxes': tf.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
        'labels': tf.VarLenFeature(tf.int64),
        # Dense data
        'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([],tf.string)

    })

# Get metadata
objects_number = tf.cast(features['objects_number'], tf.int32)
height = tf.cast(features['height'], tf.int32)
width = tf.cast(features['width'], tf.int32)
depth = tf.cast(features['depth'], tf.int32)

# Actual data
image_shape = tf.parallel_stack([height, width, depth])
bboxes_shape = tf.parallel_stack([objects_number, 4])

# BBOX data is actually dense convert it to dense tensor
bboxes = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(features['bboxes'], default_value=0)

# Since information about shape is lost reshape it
bboxes = tf.reshape(bboxes, bboxes_shape)
image = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)
image = tf.reshape(image, image_shape)
```

Notice that "image_raw" is fixed length Feature (has one element) and holds values of type "bytes", however a value of "bytes" type can itself have variable size (its a string of bytes, and can have many symbols within it).
So "image_raw" is a list with ONE element of type "bytes", which can be super big.

**To further elaborate on how it works:**
**Features** are lists of  values, those values have specific "type".

Datatypes for **features** are subset of data types for tensors, you have:

- int64 (64 bit space in memory)
- bytes (occupies as many bytes in memory as you want)
- float (occupies 32-64 bits in memory idk how much)

You can check [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes/DType)  **tensors** data types.

So you can store variable length data without `VarLenFeatures` at all (actually well you do it), but first you would need to convert it into bytes/string feature, and then decode it. 
And this is most common method.

Comment: Hi thanks, but I'm still confused about the final sentence: 'Notice that image is fixed length Feature of type "tf.string", where string itself can have variable size.' Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Pietrko What if I want to use int64 datatype? plz see my question .
 thx https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47939537/how-to-use-dataset-api-to-read-tfrecords-file-of-lists-of-variant-length/47949002#47949002

Comment: In case it is helpful, here is another example of [encoding](https://github.com/balancap/SSD-Tensorflow/blob/e0e3104d3a2cc5d830fad041d4e56ebcf84caac3/datasets/pascalvoc_to_tfrecords.py#L150) and [decoding](https://github.com/balancap/SSD-Tensorflow/blob/e0e3104d3a2cc5d830fad041d4e56ebcf84caac3/datasets/pascalvoc_common.py#L75). I am still trying to make sense of the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

@Xyz already shed some light on it. In addition, the docstring from [`parse_example_v2`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2eff2d8f08e5fae591573d0cd1fdff8f9a3df135/tensorflow/python/ops/parsing_ops.py#L79) is also rather helpful (see excerpt below):

P.s.: Given that we can easily convert arrays to bytes (`numpy.ndarray.tobytes` or `tf.io.serialize_tensor`), I wonder in which cases the `VarLenFeature` shall really be preferred.

---

For example, if one expects a `tf.float32` `VarLenFeature` `ft` and three
serialized `Example`s are provided:

```
serialized = [
  features
    { feature { key: "ft" value { float_list { value: [1.0, 2.0] } } } },
  features
    { feature []},
  features
    { feature { key: "ft" value { float_list { value: [3.0] } } }
]
```

then the output will look like:

```py
{"ft": SparseTensor(indices=[[0, 0], [0, 1], [2, 0]],
                    values=[1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
                    dense_shape=(3, 2)) }
```

If instead a `FixedLenSequenceFeature` with `default_value = -1.0` and
`shape=[]` is used then the output will look like:

```py
{"ft": [[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, -1.0]]}
```